# How to fix map wobbles during scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 app.in my application Map section on venue page wobbles when moving at the moment if i scroll quick enough the map follows the screen and appears sticky. I dont know how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated. My code for html is as follow

```
  <div style="position: fixed; height: 30vh ;width: 100%">
        <div  id="map_canvas" ></div>
    </div>
```

for .ts file of map

```
  loadMap() {
        const location = new LatLng(this.venue.latitude, this.venue.longitude);

        this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
            camera: {
              target: location,
              zoom: 18,
              tilt: 0
            }
        });

        const marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
            title: this.venue.name,
            snippet: this.venue.strapline,
            position: location,
            animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.BOUNCE
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full code or a codesandbox / stackblitz so that we are able to reproduce this issue from our side?